# Get next element with a class name without using jquery

Tags: javascript

I do not have access to jquery. I'm trying to implement an accordion, but the content element is not immediately after the header. It is something similar to the following:

```
<div class="header">...</div>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
```

So I'm adding a function to handle an onclick event on the header, which needs to then obtain the next element in the HTML source code that has the content class. How can I achieve that?

Comment: you want `querySelector`

Comment: can you share the code of your onclick event of header

Comment: like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/pkng4jee/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using querySlector on the clicked header node

```
<div class="header">
  <div>
    <div class="content">


[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.header'), function(header) {
    header.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var content = this.querySelector('.content');
        // here, "this" is the header div, and "content" is the content div
        // do majick accordion things here
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in my code. Please see the corrected version. Content isn't inside the header element.

Answer (score 0):

How about using recursive function and `nextSibling` *[get next element (not children)]*

```
<div class="header" onclick="hasClass(this)">...</div>
  <div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
<script>
function hasClass(e){
    if(e.nextSibling.children === undefined || e.nextSibling.children.length == 0){
        hasClass(e.nextSibling); //go next till find class
    }
    else{
    if(e.nextSibling.children[0].className == "content"){
        console.log(e.nextSibling.innerHTML);  //get class content html
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get this by

```
var contentDiv= document.getElementsByClassName("content");
```

Comment: I'm guessing with an accordian there will be more than one .content

Answer (score -1):

try this `document.getElementById(header).getElementsByClassName('content');`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".